# Testcafe - Invoking a RequestHook on all tests in a single declaration?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a `RequestHook` that adds some header values to every HTTP request that is made, but currently I have to import the hook into each seperate fixture file and attach it to the fixture with `.requestHooks()`.

What would be great is if I could attach the `RequestHook` to all fixtures in one declaration, possibly using the scripting API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, there is no public API to do this. I've created a [suggestion](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5364) in the official TestCafe repository. Track it to be notified about its progress.